# Extract not working on

Tags: php

I'm using the following code, the first echo works fine but the second comes up as undefined.

```
echo $_POST['text'];

extract($_POST, EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, "Form_");

echo $Form_text;
```

Comment: So where does $Fm_text come from - it magically appears from the Aether? Fm_ !== Form_

Comment: @MarkBaker `extract` is a vile thing that imports stuff from an array into the current scope... really nothing one should use, imho.

Comment: x3ro - agreed, and especially with user input

Comment: Surely it is fine with EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, how can it be a problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`extract`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) already adds `_` after prefix.

So:

```
echo $Form__text;
```

will work.

In another words, there's no need to manually add `_` in third parameter.

Your code should be like this:

```
extract($_POST, EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, "Form");

echo $Form_text;
```